# Scrollbar disappear in Touchscreen Monitors for Sencha ExtJS version 5.1.1 application

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs5, sencha-architect

Need some suggestions, looking more of a work around for prod issues. We have Sencha ExtJS version 5.1.1 application with Classic toolkit, for Touch screen devices scrollbar just disappearing. From my research it came out that I need to upgrade to 5.1.2 to resolve. which we'll do in future planning. I am currently looking for any workarounds for our clients ! Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Recreate issue :
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3qo&view/editor

Please select the 5.1.1 version with the classic toolkit in the Touchscreen machine. Scrollbar isn't disappearing for dropdown.

Comment: Please setup a fiddle (fiddle.sencha.com) with an example. Without a fiddle it is hard find out what you want and to supply you amn answer.

Comment: @Dinkheller please find fiddle setup.  If you go there and select 5.1.1 version with classic toolkit, you won't able to see dropdown list scroll bar in touchscreen machine that's the cause. Our users who uses touchscreen machines they were not able to see scrollbar.  

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3qo&view/editor

Comment: I ran the example with 5.1.1 (there is only the classic toolkit9 with Classic and Neptune design on an iPad and the toolbar shows up. Cannot reproduce the problem. The only thing I could think of is, that you might want ot use the latest Sencha CMD. Some changes for the head-meta data are made through Sencha CMD.